# Wrong Compiler Error in Code Blocks

Tags: programming, c++, code-blocks

I am currently using code blocks 10.05 as a C++ compiler but I am facing a problem during building of source code (compiling) .

It displays an error that - debug program uses a wrong compiler, skipping...

I am using a GNU compiler from console application menu . Please help to rectify problem

Comment: i too facing same problem . please help..

Comment: Does it work if you try and compile the source code using command line gcc?

Comment: i honestly do not understand what you have said..

Comment: I have tried the default "Hello World" from a new C++ console project and it builds and runs fine, could you please provide a screenshot of the error ? What templare are you using ?

Comment: I mean does it work if you run: `gcc hello.c -o hello` or `g++ hello.cpp -o hello` from a terminal? You need to replace hello.c/hello.cpp with your source file.

Comment: Can you upload the Hello World program (or anything that fails to compile?) You can archive it by right-clicking the project dir and selecting "Create archive".

Comment: Post up the `Build log` after changing settings in `"Settings -> Compiler and Debugger -> Global Compiler Settings -> Other Settings (it's the rightmost tab) -> Compiler Logging"` to `"Full command line"` and compiling again

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).

Answer (score 2):

Open the Settings->Compiler and debugger settings window from the menu, then change the selected compiler from the drop-down menu.